# Does Android Things support the Raspberry Pi 3 model B+?

Tags: raspberry-pi3, android-things

Has anyone tested *Android Things* on the *Raspberry Pi 3 model B+* yet?

When I attempt to boot the *Pi 3 B+* with an *Android Things* image, it remains on the initial multi-colour boot screen and nothing further happens. Power is fine and same micro SD card works with *Raspbian*.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Raspberry Pi 3 model **B+*** is not yet [officially supported by *Android Things*](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/index.html#hardware_platforms) in contrast to *Raspberry Pi 3 model B*.

Comment: @NES_4Life, _"I'd really like someone from the Android-Things team to say if they're looking at supporting it in the near future though"_. In this case you could ask [Google Android Things Community](https://plus.google.com/communities/107507328426910012281) or fill in a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192720&template=848805).

Comment: I have fill in a  feature request: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79512206

Comment: Unfortunately, Android Things still doesn't support the Raspberry Pi 3 B+. As mentioned in the question, it remains at the initial multi-color screen after switching it on.