# Using an Android GUI on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, raspberry-pi

I have recently created a Gui using python and the Qt Framework. I use the Gui To display sensor data I collect from a raspberry Pi. The Issue now is that I am not satisfied with the look and feel of the Gui and have been recommended using android instead, I was wondering is it possible to connect an android Gui to a raspberry Pi so i can read data from its GPIO?

Thanks.

Comment: @Onik I am using Raspberry Pi Model 3B+

Comment: You might use [Android Things](https://developer.android.com/things/) for this, but only for `Raspberry Pi Model 3B`, [`B+` aren't yet supported](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49434627/3290339).