# Which microcontroller (board) is the most suitable for hosting the Android operating system?

Tags: android

I'm doing a project regarding IoT and my microcontroller will need to communicate Bluetooth with some sensors. I have some Android APKs available to make the connection. I have already tried Banana Pi but it does not support the BLE connection. I tried Raspberry Pi 3 B + but I have some problems with choosing the right image.

**I wanted to know if anyone could recommend me some alternative board to use with Android operating system. The board must have Bluetooth BLE and Wi-fi module.**

Thank you

Comment: Have you considered using [Android Things](https://developer.android.com/things/get-started). If it fits, pay attention `Raspberry Pi 3 B +` isn't supported, only [Raspberry Pi 3 B](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49435727/3290339).

Comment: I managed to install an unofficial version of Android 8.1 on Raspberry 3 B+ but I have a problem with Bluetooth. The user interface is not able to turn on Bluetooth. For this reason, I look for advice on single-board alternatives.

Comment: No microcontroller board supports Android.