# Is it possible to run AndroidThings on Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+

Tags: raspberry-pi3, android-things

Im wondering if it is possible to run AndroidThings on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+

Ive been following this tutorial :

[Android Things - LED Blinker](https://www.hackster.io/hackstermia/android-things-led-blinker-6c23e2#toc-getting-started-2)

It seems to state that Raspberry Pi 3 Model B is supported, but does not directly say the B+ is.

Each time i download a build and flash the SD card, once inserted my Pi 3B+ stops at the rainbow screen.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thankyou

Comment: It isn't officially supported. Please, see [Does Android Things support the Raspberry Pi 3 model B+?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49434627/3290339)

Comment: Thankyou so much Onik, much appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Android Things support the Raspberry Pi 3 model B+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49434627/does-android-things-support-the-raspberry-pi-3-model-b)